# App crashes if no answer is given

Tags: android

My app is a timed math game. Answer as many questions as you can before the timer runs out. When the time runs out, The GameOverActivity is now the current activity. I've realized that if I give no answer, the app will crash. If I give at least 1 answer, the app doesn't crash and everything is normal. I'm not sure where the flaw in my code exista.

This is the Main Activity

```
package stormy.incremental.randomtest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class FastMathActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int rand1, rand2, randDecider, correctAnswer, falseAnswer, problemsSolved;
    String response,sumStr;
    MyCountDownTimer myCountDownTimer;

    int score;

    Random r;
    TextView randTV1, randTV2, scoreTV, sumTV, problemsSolvedTV, timerTV;
    Button choice1, choice2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_random_test);
        problemsSolved =0;
        falseAnswer = 1;

//Initializing TextViews

        timerTV = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer));

        randTV1 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.rand1));
        randTV2 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.rand2));
        sumTV = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.sum));
        scoreTV = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.score));
        problemsSolvedTV = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.problemsSolved));

        choice1 = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.choice1));
        choice2 = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.choice2));

//Initializing a Random
        r = new Random();

//Set the first question
        setRandomProblem();

//Starting the timer
        myCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(timerTV, 5000, 1000);
        myCountDownTimer.start();

// Button Listeners
        choice1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


              checkResponse((Button)v);
              setRandomProblem();

            }
        });
        choice2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                checkResponse((Button)v);
                setRandomProblem();

            }
        });
    }
    public void checkResponse(Button v) {


//Convert the response and correctAnswer to String in order to compare values
        response = v.getText().toString();
        sumStr = Integer.toString(correctAnswer);

//If the user clicks the correct answer, increment score
        if ((response.equals(sumStr))) {
            score++;
            scoreTV.setText(score+"");
          }

//Increment the total amount of problems solved

        problemsSolved++;
        problemsSolvedTV.setText(problemsSolved+"");

//Keep track of the score within the timer
        myCountDownTimer.recordScore(score,problemsSolved);
    }

    private void setRandomProblem() {

//Assigning random values to ints
        rand1 = r.nextInt(5 - 1) + 1;
        rand2 = r.nextInt(5 - 1) + 1;
        randDecider = r.nextInt(2) + 1;

//The correctAnswer of the randoms
        correctAnswer = rand1 + rand2;

//Setting the texts of the random values
        randTV1.setText(rand1 + "");
        randTV2.setText(rand2 + "");

//If the random deciding number is 1, set answer on choice1
        if (randDecider == 1) {
            choice1.setText(correctAnswer + "");
            choice2.setText(correctAnswer + falseAnswer + "");
        }
        //If the random deciding number is 2, set answer on choice2
        else {
            choice1.setText(correctAnswer + falseAnswer + "");
            choice2.setText(correctAnswer + "");
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
//Stop the timer
        myCountDownTimer.cancel();
    }

    }
```

This is the GameOverActivity

```
package stormy.incremental.randomtest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by kamalu on 12/25/2017.
 */

public class GameOverActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView scoreTV, problemsSolvedTV, percentageTV;
    int score, problemsSolved, percentage;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gameover);

//Initializing TextViews
        scoreTV = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.score));
        problemsSolvedTV = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.problemsSolved));
        percentageTV = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.percentage));

//Opening Bundle and assigning values
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        score = extras.getInt("score");
        problemsSolved = extras.getInt("problemsSolved");

//calculating the accuracy
       percentage = (score/problemsSolved)*100;

//Displaying the score
        percentageTV.setText(percentage+"");
        scoreTV.setText(score+"");
        problemsSolvedTV.setText(problemsSolved+"");
    }

//Start the game over
    public void retry(View v){
        Intent retryIntent = new Intent(GameOverActivity.this, FastMathActivity.class);
        startActivity(retryIntent);
    }
    public void onBackPressed()
    {

    }
}
```

This is the Timer. I believe it to be important to note that the onFinish() method in this class starts the GameOverActivity.

```
package stormy.incremental.randomtest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

TextView textCounter;
int score,problemsSolved;

public MyCountDownTimer(TextView textCounter, long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    this.textCounter = textCounter;

}

@Override
public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished){

    textCounter.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
}

@Override
public void onFinish () {
       Intent gameOverIntent = new Intent(textCounter.getContext(), GameOverActivity.class);
       gameOverIntent.putExtra("score", score);
       gameOverIntent.putExtra("problemsSolved", problemsSolved);
       textCounter.getContext().startActivity(gameOverIntent);

}

//Keep track of the scores
    public void recordScore(int score,int problemsSolved){
    this.problemsSolved = problemsSolved;
    this.score = score;
    }

}
```

Comment: Crash with what error?

Comment: You've given us a lot of code, and it would be helpful if you could at least point out which lines of code are causing the error.  Most folks on SO won't have the patience to read through everything.

Comment: @Carcigenicate java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero. I guess this means that if no answer is given the the variables will be 0 and Java isn't able to move forward. How can I manuever this?

Comment: @LinuxOracleUser Post that in the question, complete with the stack trace.

Comment: @LinuxOracleUser And check if the variable holds a 0 before trying division on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check:

```
//calculating the accuracy
percentage = (score/problemsSolved)*100;
```

if problemsSolved = 0, your app will crash with exeptions: `java.lang.ArithmeticException`
You can refer:

```
if (problemSolved != 0){
    //calculating the accuracy
    percentage = (score/problemsSolved)*100;
} else {
    // handle with problemSolved = 0;
}
```

I hope it can help your problem!